# htttp и https на ru.stackoverflow.com

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, https

Открываю сайт по https протоколу. Все хорошо. Переход по вопросам, поиску, профилю - все работает через https.

Но почему на верхней панели **Входяшие** и **Достижения** содержат ссылки ведущие на http версию сайта?

Предлагаю исправить недочет.

P.S. Meta по https протоколу не открывается в FF 44.0.2.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688/178988

Comment: Да, косяку с SSL-сертификатом Меты скоро будет год. В целом, [вот суть](http://pastebin.com/QjHrG5kb).

Comment: Мне тоже это надоедает. Захожу по https на ru, а потом оказываюсь на http на meta.ru